# GPS only works when I click Reset on Arduino or Reopen Serial Monitor

Tags: serial, tinygps

I cannot work this out!

My Ublox 7n GPS module will only print data in the serial monitor once when I either click reset on my Arduino Uno or reopen and close my Serial monitor.

So whenever I have the serial monitor open and click reset on my Arduino it quickly spits out all the data on it and then stops, same when I open the serial monitor after being closed.

Here is my code:

```
#include "TinyGPS++.h"
void displayInfo();
const unsigned long PUBLISH_PERIOD = 1000;
double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
TinyGPSPlus gps;
unsigned long lastPublish = 0;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{

    while (Serial.available() > 0) {

      if (gps.encode(Serial.read())) {
        displayInfo();
     }
    }
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("new");
}

void displayInfo()
{
  if (millis() - lastPublish >= PUBLISH_PERIOD) {
    lastPublish = millis();
    char buf[128];
    delay(1000);

    if (gps.location.isValid()) {
      snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%lf,%lf", gps.location.lat(), gps.location.lng());
      //  Serial.println(buf);
     latitude = gps.location.lat();
     longitude = gps.location.lng();
     Serial.println(gps.location.lat());
     Serial.println(gps.location.lng());
     Serial.println(latitude, 8);
     Serial.println(longitude, 8);
      }
  else {
    Serial.println("no location");
  }
}
}
```

I've attached an image of my serial monitor, the gps data came through when I closed and reopened it.

[image: Serial]

Comment: opening Serial Monitor resets Uno

Comment: ah well that solves minor part. Any idea why it is doing what can be seen?

Comment: `gps.encode(Serial.read())` is always false later?

Comment: I think it has to do with the millis() part. the PPS is flickering on the ublox, I think the clock might be damaged or something. I dont have anything connected to the PPS leg on the GPS though.